# Importing anorm.SQL in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10, anorm

- IntelliJ 13 Community Edition
- Play Framework 2.2
- Scala 2.10.2

I am importing anorm._ and using SQL in my object.  The object starts off as follows:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Play.current
import anorm._

object Walks extends Controller {

 val futureWalksSql = SQL("SELECT * FROM walks where evt_date > now()")
```

IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol SQL.  If I ctrl+Enter, after `anorm.` there is no SQL option, although there is a .Sql trait, object and class.

When I run the play project, it all works just fine, with no compilation errors so this Scala is syntactically correct but IntelliJ isn't picking this up.  I have created the idea files by calling `idea` from within the play console and I've also tried `idea with-sources=yes`.

How do I get IntelliJ Community Editon to pick up anorm.SQL?  What is so special about this object?  I'm still learning Scala and so this might be a Scala issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a method defined in a package object `anorm`. So when you `import anorm._` you import the entire package with the package object as well. I have actually no clue why Idea does not pick this up. But if you look into the package object sources you can see that the `SQL` method is just a wrapper on `anorm.Sql.sql(inSql: String)`.

As a workaround you may try to import `anorm.Sql._` and use `sql("select 1")` instead of `SQL("select 1")`